# Identifiability of multinomial logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, inference, identifiability

What are the sufficient conditions for identifiability of regression coefficients in multinomial logistic regression generally?

Comment: Can you say more about where you are confused and what you need to understand?

Comment: I want to know what is the sufficient conditions for identifiability of regression coefficients in multinomial logistic regression.